# Why is heroku dyno consuming a bunch of hours?

Tags: heroku

So I currently have a Java Spring Boot app deployed on Heroku and is the only dyno I have deployed on the account. I had made a call to it and it started up the server but then immediately logged ~1.2 hours off of my free dyno hours. I only had it open for ~10 minutes and then with the added 30 minutes to go to sleep it should only have logged 40 minutes. Is it possibly because it is making multiple calls to the same dyno that it is spinning up multiple thread and then charging double? What causes this?

Comment: Kindly add a piece of code that you are trying to run. That could help understand where the time is being consumed more.

Comment: Github link to the project: https://github.com/yodigi7/quiplash
I am only deploying the Backend folder which is a Java Spring application